# memcached check server is online

Tags: php, memcached

I am using the **memcached** php extension, when you run `addServer` the documentation says no connection is established to the server, so if a memcached server goes down it would still get added.

How can I check that the server is available? Using memcached and not memcache extension so I can't use `getServerStatus`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [getStats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.getstats.php) to check the stats of your servers:

```
<?php
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

print_r($m->getStats());
?>
```

Comment: if the server was down would it not appear in the key of the `getStats` returned array?

Answer (score 1):

In the answer above if in the array of stats return PID -1 the server is down, any other is on.